# How to submit current form in ng-repeat angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, nested-forms

I need am not able to access the *$scope.mainform.subform.submitted* property in my script. My html goes as below.

```html
<div ng-form="mainform">
    <div ng-repeat="dependent in DependentDetails">
        <ng-form name="subform">
            <input type="text" class="textbox" ng-model="dependent.FirstName"/>
                    
            @*Same goes for other personal details*@
                    
            <input type="button" id="submitbutton"  value="Save"  ng-model="Submit" ng-click="saveDependentDetailsClick($event, $index, dependent)" />
        </ng-form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I think that it's not correct to use `<ng-form name="subform">...</div>` in `ng-repeat` in a way you have used it because you will end up with multiple forms having same name(`subform`) within the same scope therefore you can't refer to each of these forms as they have not unique name providing you with reference to them.
You will also end up with multiple submit buttons with the same `id="submitbutton"` in same html document which is an invalid html.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```js
var app = angular
  .module('MyApp', [
  ])
.controller('Main', ['$scope', function ($scope) { 
    $scope.DependentDetails = [{"FirstName":""},{"FirstName":""}];
  
  $scope.saveDependentDetailsClick = function(DependentDetails){
    
    console.log(DependentDetails);
    }
}])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
 <div class="main-content" ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="Main as myCtrl">
     <div ng-form="mainform">
        <div ng-repeat="dependent in DependentDetails">
            <ng-form name="subform">
                  <input type="text" class="textbox" ng-model="dependent.FirstName"/>
               <input type="button" value="Save" ng-click="saveDependentDetailsClick(dependent)" />
            </ng-form>
         </div>
         
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But i need to show submit button at the end of each dependent details and when user clicks on the  'Save', i need to access that particular form's submitted property. When I debug, it shows other properties like valid, pristine etc but 'submitted' is visible.